# GetInt was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

Am I doing anything wrong with sharedPreferences in flutter.

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
int score;
int storedScore;
final String uid;
StoredData(this.uid) {
_initialize();
_readValues();
}

_initialize() async {
prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();}

_readValues() {
score = prefs.getInt("score") ?? 0;
storedScore = prefs.getInt("storedScore") ?? 0;}
```

error:
I/flutter (18698): The method 'getInt' was called on null.
I/flutter (18698): Receiver: null
I/flutter (18698): Tried calling: getInt("score")
The relevant error-causing widget was:
I/flutter (18698):   HomeScreen file:///D:/flutter/trivia_iq/trivia_iq/lib/main.dart:24:33

This is not in the main.dart file but I am getting this.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your _initialize method is an async function, which won't block other operations from executing. so when _readValues runs this prefs is null. to get a better understanding of async/await pls read documentation https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await

Answer (score 0):

In "StoredData()" constructor you should use await also when calling "_initialize()" method:

```
await _initialize();
```

If not "_readValues()" would be called when sharedPreferences are not yet initialized.

But because use of async on constructors is not permitted, you should change initialize() like this:

```
_initialize() async {
prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
score = prefs.getInt("score") ?? 0;
storedScore = prefs.getInt("storedScore") ?? 0;
}
```

In your widget you can do something like this:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget{

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return MaterialApp(
      home: FutureBuilder(
      future: StoredData._initialize(),
      builder: (_,snap){
        if (snap.connectionState==ConnectionState.done)
        return Text("Settings loaded");
        else
        return Text("Loading settings...");
      }
      ),);
  }
}


class StoredData {
      static SharedPreferences _prefs;
      static int score;
      static int storedScore;
      final String uid;

      StoredData(this.uid);

      static Future _initialize() async {
        _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        score = _prefs.getInt("score") ?? 0;
        storedScore = _prefs.getInt("storedScore") ?? 0;
      }
}
```

Comment: I am getting null back shouldn't I be getting 0 instead? same there mate

Comment: Hello @KiranBhandari you get null because "prefs" is null, and "score" is not initialised yet. Where you create the StoredData object you should wait until _initialize() is finished. You can do with a bool like : bool loaded = false; set to true at the end of "_initialize()"

Comment: @KiranBhandari I have added a sample code using a FutureBuilder.

Comment: not working in my machine. Same thing is happeing with others too don't know why code is not working properly. Previously,this was not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This gives null as shared preference object object haven't created till now, and you are using it somewhere.

You have to add Future as you do await for some background work

```
  Future<Void> _initialize() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }
```

**Calling Function Like:**

```
_initialize().then((value) => _readValues());
```

Comment: I am getting null back shouldn't I be getting 0 instead?

Comment: I tried on my end it's giving me 0, call the method the same way which I did. kill and   ReRun App again.

Comment: @KiranBhandari: I have doubt whether you missed something or not. Can you provide me latest code which you have, it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
StoredData(this.uid) {
_initialize().then((value) => _readValues());
shouldStoreInFirebase();}

Future<void> _initialize() async {
prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();}
_readValues() {
score = prefs.getInt("score") ?? 1;
storedScore = prefs.getInt("storedScore") ?? 0;
```

}